# Compilation difference in Spyder IDE and Python intrepeter

Tags: python, spyder

This problem may seem a little strange, but a while (about 1-2 weeks) ago I wrote a little Python script which I tested and everything worked just fine. Today when I was taking lines from this latter script, the lines would run without any error in the Spyder IDE Python console, but when I try to put those same line in a new `.py` file, Spyder gives me errors!

So I tried to compile the old script again, then I got errors!

A few examples to maybe clear things up:

1. I load and image using PIL Image:  `im = Image.open("test.jpg")`
   then in the Spyder console I can do: `im.layers` which gives me the number of color channels. Even though this attribute doesn't exist in PIL Image docs!
   But using this same attribute in a python file would give an error!
2. Using: `a = array( [ [ 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [...] ] )` I can create a 2D array (or matrix). This is possible through Spyder, but not regular Python interpreter (which leads to NameError: global name 'array' is not defined
   )!

And a few more examples like these.

Could anyone help me understand what is going on, knowing that I'm sort of a Python noob?

Python version: 2.7.6 | GCC 4.8.2 | Spyder 2.2.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spyder 2.2.5 is an older version (the last version is 2.3.4).  When it is started automatically imports numpy and matplotlib.  The regular Python interpreter  needs an explicit `import numpy as np` in order to define an array, `A=np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])`.

Comment: A missing import shouldn't cause a syntax error, though, or am I mistaken? (At least as long as you aren't importing from `__future__`.) Can you change the syntax from within Python code?

Comment: I think @Hamed refers to an error like this one:  a = array( [ [ 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6] ] )
NameError: name 'array' is not defined

Comment: @mittag  He's probably right, actually it was my mistake that I had wrote syntax error!

Comment: How could you explain the attribute `layers` ?

Comment: @xecafe: but that's a `NameError`, not a syntax error. A `NameError` implies that the code is actually running, which in turn implies that it was correctly parsed. But a syntax error means that the code couldn't even be parsed, let alone run, so there can't possibly be any runtime errors!